# How to select rows where values are greater based on values of other column in SQL

Tags: sql

Say you have the following table:

| iD | Date | region | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-06-01 | NC | 3 |
| 2 | 2013-06-01 | NA | 5 |
| 3 | 2013-06-02 | NC | 7 |
| 4 | 2013-06-02 | NA | 2 |

I want to select (date, region, cases) only when the cases of NC are greater than those of NA in a given day. For example rows 3 and 4 meet this condition.

Desired output:

| iD | Date | region | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2013-06-02 | NC | 7 |
| 4 | 2013-06-02 | NA | 2 |

Comment: Please add the desired output ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Date`s that satisfy your condition with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Date
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Date
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'NC' THEN Cases END) >
       MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'NA' THEN Cases END)
```

Use the above query as a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE Date IN (
  SELECT Date
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Date
  HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'NC' THEN Cases END) >
         MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'NA' THEN Cases END) 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dd890b7c3f47d72a4119d9f9e2dc4e3).